# Compare two Objects and return only unique data

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have two objects and I want to extract only the data that is unique using underscore js.

**Object 1 (default)**

```
{
   players: "Players: ",
   tableLimit: "Table Limits:",
   newCardBtn: "Add New Card",
   existingCard: "Use existing one",
   contactUs: "Contact Us",
   test: {
      table: 'test'
   }
}
```

**Object 2 (overwrite)**

```
  {
    players: "Players: ",
    tableLimit: "Table Limits:",
    newCardBtn: "Add New Card",
    existingCard: "Use existing one",
    test: {
      table: 'test'
    }
  }
```

The end result should return a list with data that is missing from overwrite. In our case, it should return `contactUs: "Contact Us"`

Till now I have this but it returns all data from default object without the custom:

```
var def = {
    players: "Players: ",
    tableLimit: "Table Limits:",
    newCardBtn: "Add New Card",
    existingCard: "Use existing one",
    contactUs: "Contact Us",
    test: {
      table: 'test'
   }
}

var custom = {
    players: "Players: ",
    tableLimit: "Table Limits:",
    newCardBtn: "Add New Card",
    existingCard: "Use existing one",
    test: {
      table: 'test'
   }
}

var out = JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, def, custom));
fs.writeFile("./out.js", out);
```

Comment: I know mentioned post is not using `underscore`.  If you want answer to be **in underscore only**, please decline it and add necessary information in question. If you are fine with pure JS version, please accept duplicate so that no one else can answer this post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will parse obj1 and if there is no matching property with a matching value in obj2 then it is added to obj3.  You can see the results in the output...

```js
var obj1 = {
  players: "Players: ",
  tableLimit: "Table Limits:",
  newCardBtn: "Add New Card",
  existingCard: "Use existing one",
  contactUs: "Contact Us",
};

var obj2 = {
  players: "Players: ",
  tableLimit: "Table Limits:",
  newCardBtn: "Add New Card",
  existingCard: "Use existing one",
};
  
var obj3 = (function() {
  result = {};
  for (var k in obj1) {
    if (obj2[k] != obj1[k]) {
      result[k] = obj1[k];
    }
  }
  return result;
})();

console.log(obj3);
```

Comment: Just a question, if you are just going to give a function in pure js that gets difference, its better to mark this as dupe.

Comment: @Rajesh While I agree that the question you proposed as a duplicate will give the OP a working solution, it's also massive overkill for this simple scenario.  My answer would never be a working, relevant answer to the question you proposed as a duplicate, so I consider this more suitable than the answer to the question you linked.  I think if you don't need a deeper comparison, most people would prefer the look of this code to the linked.

Comment: Agree to your point, but I guess this is where things get grey. Your answer is apt for this situation where answer in dupe is more generic. However, for a beginner, your answer will make more sense, but for a experienced reader, this would be like duplicating content and this might attract downvotes. Hope people do consider this difference before choosing their votes.